# Incompatibility with Fluent-API when upgrading from Entity Framework 4.1 to 4.3 using Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4

All of a sudden I started receiving the following error after upgrading from EF 4.1 to 4.3.

> Inner exception: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The operation failed because an index or statistics with name 'IX_AccountId' already exists on table 'User'.

The following is the relevant code creating this error.

```cs
public class Account {

    public Account() {
        Users = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; private set; }

}

public class User {

    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Account>()
            .HasMany<User>(a => a.Users)
            .WithRequired()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.AccountId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.Account)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.AccountId);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I now need now need to explicitly declare the navigation properties within the  `WithMany` above.

This fixed my problem:

```cs
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasRequired(u => u.Account)
            .WithMany(a => a.Users)
            .HasForeignKey(u => u.AccountId);
```